# How can I fit Keshava temple and Mysore in a day trip from Bangalore? (with public transport)

Tags: public-transport, india, buses, bangalore, south-india

To get to Keshava temple from Bangalore I need to follow the Bangalore-Mandya, Mandya-Bannur, Bannur-Somnathpur route. Then I'm wondering since it's more of the same direction to Mysore, can I also go to Mysore afterward and take a night bus/train back?

Comment: I voted to leave this Q open as the way it is stated in the title it is clearly not WANTA and we have had similar Qs by high rep users, e.g. [one about seeing a bunch of Paris sites as a day trip from London](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/69211/32134).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update

We did it in one day.
We took a train to Mandya from ERN at around 9. It arrived at 11:30 (it took longer due to the delay) Then from Mandya city we took a direct public bus to Somnathpur. We arrived at around 1:40. 
Then from the temple we took first a bus to Bannur then from there it was easy to jump on a bus to Mysore. We only did the palace in Mysore and then take a train at 6-ish and arrive at 9-ish in Bangalore. 
In Bangalore we still went to the night food street.

It was quite a day but easier than we tought.
For the same we also did a day trip from Kochi to Kottayam, did a backwater public boat to Alleppey then took a bus bck to Kochi from Alleppey.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can actually I come from Mysore, and the temple is just 30+ km's away, and good express trains to Bangalore are available till 20:30

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any direct buses from Mysore to the temple? My concern is mostly from Bangalore to the temple, needs 2 changes of the bus

Comment: Unfortunately i don't think so there are any at least to that temple, you can hire a car or you can drive one yourself ;) btw when are you planning to go there?

Comment: This saturday I guess. I don't think I would rent a car. Do you think I can use uber from the temple to mysore?

Comment: That's way out of the coverage area of Uber. I'm around in town that day let me know if I could help?

Comment: I hope you had less difficulties going to the temple.