# Which entrance to use for the Louvre?

Tags: planning, the-louvre

Is there a good thought process as to which entrance to use to enter the Louvre?

I understand the Pyramid can have very long queues, however, I am wondering if next week will be low-season, such that there is no advantage to using the alternate entrances and pre-buying tickets online.

[image]

Comment: See this bounty winning answer: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69211/london-paris-time-critical-agenda-for-the-louvre-and-rodin-museum/69626#69626

Comment: I have been at the Louvre at different times in the year and at no single day have seen it quiet. The Pyramide queue can be an hour, it can be two hours, I have never seen it with the museum open without any queue. Do not forget you will have to deal with a double queue, one to get into the building and a second to get into the museum. September/October is still pretty busy, come November or February to see Paris with the fewest tourists.

Comment: The best entrance is the one to the Musee D'orsay.  Forget the louvre - it's a mindboggling thing on the planet, but, just too many people.  You have a vast number of other great choices in Paris.

Comment: If you are in Paris for two or more days and plan to see more museums, I'd recommend getting the [Museum Pass](http://en.parismuseumpass.com). Use the pyramid entrance but skip the queue. Ditto for most other landmarks. I used it twice and it never took more than 5 minutes to navigate "both" queues

Comment: @RedBaron: good idea.  Bought a pair of passes this morning

Answer (score 5):

*This answer applies only with a precondition.*

**If** you can buy Louvre tickets in your hotel, do so. Then choose the pyramid entrance, ignore the entire queue and walk right up to the pyramid, where you can directly enter based upon your pre-bought tickets.

Comment: I have seen the pyramide entrance with a double Q, one for those with and one for those without a ticket. So having a ticket is no guaranty for queueless entry. I would get the ticket, check the Q situation and if busy, look for one of the other entrances.

Answer (score 3):

Supposedly there's a smoke shop (tabac) in the Carrousel just a short walk from the Pyramid that sells tickets. Get your tickets there and skip the extremely long line at the Pyramid for non-ticket holders and get in the shorter (or non-existent) line for ticket holders.