# Stairwell inside The Met Manhattan

Tags: new-york-city, museums, accessibility

I am planning my first trip to the Metropolitan Museum of Art. I have all the galleries I want to see charted out, and I almost have an optimal path through The Met. But I have a specific question.

On [this map](http://maps.metmuseum.org/) , on level 1 gallery 351 in Arts of Africa, there is stairwell indicated just below. But if I go to level 2 (on the left side selector), there is no accompanying stairwell indicated in this same position. On other positions in the map level 1 stairwells have accompanying level 2 stairwells.

So if I take the stairwell adjacent to gallery 351, will I end up on the second floor right next to gallery 801? Or does this stairwell only go down? Does the nearby elevator go up?

I want to go from LVL1 Greek and roman, to LVL2 19th Century European, to LVL1 modern and contemporary.

Comment: Why do you care about such minutiae details? Wouldn't an 'optimal' path save you a couple of minutes at most?

Comment: @JonathanReez, planning a [Met run](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWRPMW-bjyc)?

Comment: @JonathanReez it's a fine question. People with mobility issues have to think these kinds of things over carefully beforehand for obvious reasons. Also the OP might be time constrained, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69211/london-paris-time-critical-agenda-for-the-louvre-and-rodin-museum  It's a good question and I hope there's a killer answer for it.

Comment: Why not plan to use the stairs at gallery 160 or 163? That allows you to go through the Greek and Roman Art on the Mezzanine level (stick to one side as you'll be doubling back), then using the same stairs, go up to galleries 175 and 176 (more Greek and Roman art) on the way to 800.

Comment: My interpretation of the map matches yours (those stairs don't go up, but the elevator likely does), but I'm on the wrong side of the country to ground truth it for you. Worst case is you detour a slight bit and take the stairs at 160/163, and I'm 95% sure I remember those existing, and you can come back and update this question to let us know how it went.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no stairs up at the location, but there is an elevator up.